# Change column value with Dask DataFrame loc

Tags: python, pandas, dask, pandas-loc

I have a huge database, which I need to change the value of a column according to a certain condition.

In Pandas I execute the following code to accomplish what I want:

```py
df.loc[
        (df['ID_CRITERIO_APURACAO'] == TipoDestinatario.RESIDENCIAL.value) &
        (df['CODG_GRUPO_TENSAO'] == 8) &
        (df['CONSUMO'].between(0, 30)),
        'DESCONTO'
    ] = 35
```

How can I do something similar in Dask?

Comment: Dask usually works exactly the same way than pandas. Have you tried your code with a Dask dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it didn't work.
Returns the following error:
TypeError: '_LocIndexer' does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0):

`Dask` doesn't support inplace mutation. Try this:

```
condition = (df['ID_CRITERIO_APURACAO'] == TipoDestinatario.RESIDENCIAL.value) &
    (df['CODG_GRUPO_TENSAO'] == 8) &
    (df['CONSUMO'].between(0, 30))

desconto = df.where(condition, 35)
df['DESCONTO'] = desconto
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.
TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame

Comment: What kind of DataFrame is `TipoDestinatario` ?

Comment: It seems you can't create columns on `dask`. Try what I edited now. Tell me if at least the `dd.Series` "desconto" is created

Comment: TipoDestinatario is an enum.
It did not work, the same error occurred:
`TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame.`

Even trying to change a column already created, the same perssite error.